# Can overflow:hidden affect layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

There's no way for me to explain this except to refer to the following [example on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f2RT/1/)- in it, the last BLUE box does not extend to 100% of the width as expected after I introduce an overflow:hidden attribute.

I was under the impression overflow:hidden would affect visibility aspects only, and not interfere with layout.  Can someone explain what is going on in this example?

**EDIT:** 
This problem seems limited to webkit browsers (e.g. Chrome)

Comment: What browser are you seeing these issues in? It looks ok to me in FF

Comment: im seeing what he's pointing out with chrome. so probably webkit

Comment: Side-note: you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID, e.g. blue and red. That's not causing this issue though, which I can see in Chrome/Lin.

Comment: i think there are some problems with your styles. first, you can't use 2 ids twice(use classes). second, i don't think you're clearing your floats here

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case for Chrome(/Win) since at least v20.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is because `overflow: hidden`, among other properties, introduces a new [*block formatting context*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting).

You can read about the effects in this great article:
[The magic of overflow: hidden](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

**UPDATE:** I've [rewritten your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f2RT/3/) into something that is working (tested on Chrome). Instead of defining `margin-left` on the `#red` and `#blue` (which would act differently due to `overflow: hidden`), I've put a `margin-right` on `#yellow`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa- Awesome- thanks for the direction and the rewrite

Comment: The article is not available any longer (the link is broke). Sad.