# HTML CSS: fix and stretch width two column layout

Tags: html, css, layout

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 600px">

    <div style="float:left; width: 100px">
        left fixed-width column
    </div>
    <div style="???">
        right stretching column (the width should be 700px in this case.)
    </div>

</div>
```

What's the standard way to create two column layout where the left one is fixed-size and the right one stretches?

- I would like both columns' styles are independent. I found a couple of solutions here, but if I change the width of the left column, the right column's style (e.g. margin) need to be changed along with it.
- I don't need to support old browsers. If it's standard, it's just okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `overflow: hidden` to the second div. This will introduce a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). You can find some more information in [Can overflow:hidden affect layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout/6128264#6128264).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruYjT/)

Comment: @user1392013 If you are satisfied, you can accept my answer with the tickmark on the left of my answer.

Comment: **You must be very careful about setting overflow: hidden**... remember this will hide the content if it extends beyond the allocated area! Even if you will have a fixed amount of content, users have control over certain browser display that can affect your layout, such as font size. If the user has increased their font-size for more comfortable reading, it may render the content of your right div larger than the allocated space and the "overflow: hidden" will mean it won't be visible to that user. Is it worth alienating customers for the sake of an extra css value to change?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Hm, there is no need to vilify `overflow: hidden`. If you know what you're doing, it is a great tool. If you look at my example and take away `height: 200px`, which I only added for visibility reasons, it won't have any problem with bigger font sizes. Your last sentence is so demagogue that I won't even reply to it :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa It can be useful, but as you say yourself *if you know what you're doing*, hence my advice to *use carefully* - I didn't say not to use. We don't know the OPs application or experience, so it may be an unsuitable approach in reality. Used incorrectly it can be an accessibility nightmare & I speak from experience - we've had clients move to us for this very reason. When they tried to add more text it got cut off because poor design didn't allow flexibility for their edits (it hid overflow to "look nice"). These are actual real-life issues, not "demagogue" as you dismissed them...

Comment: Besides, sometimes its important to state the obvious here - even if the OP knows what they're doing, it doesn't mean someone else who reads this answer will :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a div to wrap both columns (and center them as a block, if you like)--then set the first column's width, and use absolute positioning on the second column to make its left border the edge of the first column and its right border the edge of the wrapper.

```
<div style="width:auto; min-width:500px; margin:30px; position:relative; top:0px;">

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; padding:15px; background-color:aqua;">
</div>

<div style="height:100px; padding:15px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:100px; right:0px;  background-color:blue;">
</div>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8kca/)