# How do I do the css for this?

Tags: css, layout

[image]

I am new to css and this has me stumped.

1. How do I get the parent div to always contain its children? As soon as I start using floats for alignment the parent stops containing children.
2. I actually do not want to float things. I want to align them. How do we do alignments and margins in css and not yet hardcode all dimensions?
3. Can someone kindly profive the css for this? Lets assume for the sake of this example that the total width is 960px and all margins are 15px;

Comment: What do you mean by "aligning" the elements?

Comment: float does not explain the green element. I don't want it 'float' to the bottom(which makes no sense) I want it to 'sink' to the bottom. So basically I want it aligned to the bottom.

Comment: In that case, I'd say float the purple and blue elements, clear the green one (i.e. solution #1 in @Konrads answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see a clear and flexible version:

```js
#container { background: gray; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; }
#left { background: purple; width: 200px; float: left; margin: 0 15px 15px 0; } 
#content { background: blue; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 0 15px 0 } 
#footer { background: green; height: 50px; clear: left; }
```

Even the `width` and `height` you see set is unnecessary, boxes can adjust to their content when omitted, I just added them for demo purposes.

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/ge4ax/)
- [`overflow: hidden` affecting layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout/6128264#6128264)
- [Chris Coyier: All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: @NVM Most of his articles are brilliant.

Answer (score 7):

Three alternatives:

1. Set `clear: both` on the green element.
2. Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent container.
3. Use [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on the parent container.

Comment: In this case, we'd get a free clearfix from the green element (by applying `clear: both` to it).

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/kMQbt/

Html:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="purple">
     purple
 </div>
 <div id="blue">
     blue
 </div>
 <div id="green">
     green
 </div>
</div>​
```

Css:

```
#parent{
 width: 960px;
 background-color: grey;    
 float:none;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#purple{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 float:left;   
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 background-color: purple;
}
#green{
 width: 930px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;  
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

#blue{
 width: 715px;
 float:left;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 15px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

​

Comment: Not quite flexible, you have to specify the dimensions not to break the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Use clearfix and assign the class to your container is one of the way to fix your problem.

```
/* let's clear some floats */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }  
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }  
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<div id="main_left"></div>
<div id="main_right"></div>
</div>
<div id="last"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container
{
width:xx;
height:xx;
background:
}
#main
{
width:xx;
height:xx;
}
#main_left{
float:left;
width:xx;
height:xx;
}
#main_right
{
float:right
width:xx;
height:xx;
}
#last
{
clear:both;
width:xx;
height:xx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo http://jsfiddle.net/yTUU6/

HTML

```
<div id="contaner">
    <div id="top_left">
        left box
    </div>
    <div id="top_right">
        right box<br />
        height will be changed <br />
        <br /><br /> <br /><br />         <br /><br /> <br /><br />       <br /><br /> <br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#contaner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
#top_left{
    width: 30%;
    border:solid 1px;
    height: 200px;    
    float:left;
}
#top_right{
    width:69%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
#bottom{
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px green;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The classic way (how i learned to do it) using a clearer element in between

CSS

```
.clearer{
    clear:both;
}
#parent{
    width:500px;
    background-color:#343434;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
}

#box{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#545454;
}

#variable{
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}

#footer{
    height:40px;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color:#646464;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div id="variable">
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/4FGpS/)

Hope this helps