# Indent a block of text from the second row 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I want make format my text:

`title - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et turpis  urna. Phasellus magna elit, tempus ut accumsan posuere, suscipit vel ligula. Vestibulum mauris massa, venenatis non dignissim vestibulum,`

to look like:

```
title - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et turpis  urna.
        Phasellus magna elit, tempus ut accumsan posuere, suscipit vel ligula. Vestibulum
        mauris massa, venenatis non dignissim vestibulum,
```

I'm interesting in any solution without add change text manually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could elaborate on the format more if you really want to solve this without adding tags. What can the title include? Can the `-` serve as a delimiter?

Comment: Yes, the `-` can be delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with `margin` and `text-indent` along with the `:first-line` pseudoclass you could achieve the desired effect: here's the relevant CSS

```
p { text-indent: -2.35em ; margin-left: 2.35em  }
p:first-line { margin-left: -2.35em }
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nb88K/

Be aware that the chosen value is strictly dependent on the width of `"title"` word.

As a sidenote, If you could change the markup itself I would instead suggest to move that word from your text to a `content` property of a `:before` pseudoclass — the fact that your text is a title, from a semantic point of view, should be conveyed through the choice of the element (so I would chose a `<hn>` tag)

Comment: I have looked at `:first-line` before but I don't connect it with `text-indent`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A fast and dirty solution:

```
<pre>
    <!-- your text stuff -->
</pre>
```

Comment: Ok, I haven't write about this but I don't want solution which integrated in my code I have search global solution. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by global solution?

Comment: Something like javascript or css what can make it for example 1000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">title</div>
<div class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et turpis  urna. Phasellus magna elit, tempus ut accumsan posuere, suscipit vel ligula. Vestibulum mauris massa, venenatis non dignissim vestibulum, 
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
​.title { float: left; }
.title:after { content: '-'; display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px; }
.text { overflow: hidden; }​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ApUQd/)

The title is floated left, and `overflow: hidden;` is used to [establish a new block formatting context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout/6128264#6128264). You can do this with any `overflow` value other than the default `visible`.

The only thing in this that is not absolutely cross-browser is the `:after` pseudo-element ([which works from IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15)), but you can simply use a static `-` in your HTML instead. I have chosen to do it this way because it is cleaner and there is no unnecessary styling in the markup.

For the title you could use something more semantic like an appropriate header (`h1`, `h2`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have all text in one it isnt divided to `title` and `text` part.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski Make use of regular expressions

Comment: @MateuszRogulski Well, to format it properly you also need proper markup. You can find some hacky way to format it, but the right way would be to change the markup. A roof will never be stable if you miss the foundation.