# Why does overflow property impact element size and flow?

Tags: css

I've stumbled upon some behavior in CSS that is confusing to me. Let's say there are two block elements, first of them floated to the right ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Zsk/)):
[image]

If the overflow property is set to hidden on the non-floated element, that element is shrunk in order to accommodate for the floated element width [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Zsk/1/):
[image]

I actually don't have a problem with that, but I would like to know why that is happening. What I do have problem with is the following case in which after the overflow is set to hidden, `width` of the non-floated element is set to `100%`. I tested this in IE9, Firefox 14, Opera 12, Chrome 20 and Safari 5 on Win7, and all of them except Firefox show ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Zsk/2/)):
[image]

What I wanted and expected, and what Firefox shows, is the same as in the first picture above. So, can anyone shed some light on why all this is happening?

Comment: Related (maybe even a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout/6128264#6128264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to definition "If the container element is itself contained by something else, the floated div will sit on the right margin of the container."

Case 1: The `.container` is covering the total space available. The `.content` is taking all the space except the `.float`(the .content is not of shape rectangle here), that's what floating is. Its actually overflowing to cover the space. Its the default behaviour.

Case 2: Now you tell the `.content` to hide the overflow. So it hides the overflow it was earlier doing as a default behaviour.

Case 3: You tell the `.content` to take the full width of the parent, i.e. `.container`, so it ignores the overflow:hidden and just expands to fill the space.

If you are wondering the weird behaviour of overflow:hidden, check this **[ARTICLE](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)**

Comment: The article really helped me. Just to note, in case 1 the `.content` is actually not overflowing. You can see by yourself that the width of it is bigger than in the case 2). That is actually normal behavior with floats.