# Horizontally Centering Absolute Positioned Div

Tags: html, css, layout

As of now, I can horizontally center the image, but once I try to vertically center it (adding top-margin), the parent div also moves down as well (which is what I don't want).

Here is an image of what I am talking about: [Screenshot](http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/7972/7848d985df004d32941ca07.png)

I think the best option would be to set it to an absolute position, but then I am having issues horizontally centering it.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    height: 96px;
    width: 484px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `overflow: hidden` on the `#container`. It will introduce a new block formatting context, so the margins are not collapsed anymore.

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vRaFR/)
- [The magic of overflow: hidden](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)
- [Can overflow:hidden affect layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout/6128264#6128264)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the container is not going lower (nor it shouldn't), it's just the logo (due to the margin) that it's going lower.

Where do you want to center the image, on the header?
Give the header a fixed height and use margin or padding to center your image.
If the header's height needs to be fluid, then you could go with

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display: table-cell
}
```

hope that helps!

R