# css box model does not stretch using padding

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have a project title as a header in my webpage. This project title is within a div called "pagetitle". After the project title, i have two words which one has to be on the left and another on the right. I want a white background everything within the "pagetitle" div leaving alittle space at the bottom after the two words. I have tried "padding-bottom:10px" for the two words. However, the white background does not stretch to cover that 10px included. May I know how should i do it?

Cheers,
ZhengHong

```
<div class ="pagetitle" style="background-color:black;">
        <center style="padding: 10px 0 0 0">Executive Summary Dashboard<center>
        <br><left style="float:left; padding:0 0 10px 10px;">Subject Selected:</left><right style="float:right;padding:0 10px 10px 0; background-color:green; margin-bottom:10px;">Time frame:</right></br>
        </div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `<left>` and `<right>` element in HTML (and `<center>` is deprecated).

Comment: hi, the left, right and center are mainly for css declarations.

Comment: Then stop doing it. HTML has a limited, defined set of tags, so you cannot simply decide to use `<left>` and `<right>`. It might cause problems right now, but in the future, it can cause headaches. Please write valid HTML for your and the web's sake. If you want something for CSS declarations, use classes and IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear floats.

1. Add this to your css

   .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
   .clearfix:after { clear: both; }
   .clearfix { zoom: 1; }
2. Add class .clearfix to your top div so you have div class="pagetitle clearfix"

Comment: hi, may i know what does overflow do? if you run my code in html, you realise the green box is stretched out of the black one. my ideal black box is one that meets the green box's line at the bottom.

Comment: in my code overflow:hidden does nothing to worry about. Adding this class will generate small pieces of content before and after you div just to help you clear floats. height: 0 and overflow: hidden are there just to make this generated blocks have no dimensions at all to preserve your layout.

Comment: Note: won't work in IE7 and lower - `::after` and `::before` are supported from IE8 (with some bugs).

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are polyfills and workarounds but it will not work in <IE8 out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You have to "contain" your floats. One way to achieve that is setting `overflow: hidden` on the container element. There are a thousand other techniques though, called clearfixes (you can find a lot on the Internet), some of them involve adding an element with `clear: both` on it.

- [jsFiddle Demo with your code fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/b8Hf3/)

Some suggested reading:

- [Clearing Floats on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)
- [Can overflow:hidden affect layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout/6128264#6128264)
- http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/

Comment: hi, may i know what does overflow do? if you run my code in html, you realise the green box is stretched out of the black one. my ideal black box is one that meets the green box's line at the bottom.

Comment: @mrghost1988 Please check the jsFiddle Demo I added. I have also added some links to my answer that explain what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

-left and right are not [valid html tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)

-separate your html and style (Use external style-sheet)

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/Am7mb/)

Comment: Should have been a comment - while true, this will not solve the floating problem.

Comment: for that You can use `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` accordingly