# Div not expanding by content

Tags: html, css, height

My wrapper div is not expanding in height by it's content. On the other hand, it expands by the header div on the page, and the nav div, but not by the sidebar which lies inside another div. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        nav content goes here
    </div>
    <div id="pagecontent">
    <div id="sidebar">
        some sidebar stuff like login form
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS (only the necessary css, not like webkit box shadows):

```
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
#header {
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    height: 100%;
}
#pagecontent {
    width: 900px;
}
```

the sidebar, which has height 100%, goes outside the wrapper div, you could look at it on http://craftersinn.net

Comment: The sidebar is "floating", and as such behaves more like an absolutely positioned element.

Comment: And in your CSS you created a rule for `#content`, while the id of the html element is `pagecontent`

Comment: @finst33: See my answer below.

Comment: oops, must have slipped with the id's :P and the html isn't copied from my page, i just typed all the divs. It doesn't miss a </div> in the real code, just here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed to add css rule `overflow:hidden` in `#wrapper` css.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your wrapped CSS, also make sure your selectors are actually selecting elements:

```
<div id="pagecontent">// remove page
#content {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/bPT49/

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after

```
<div id="sidebar">
        some sidebar stuff like login form
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) on floats, especially the section "Clearing the Float".

In short, you can use `clear: both`, `overflow: hidden` or the clearfix method. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here discussed the same problem. Check for clearing floats solution and explanation about overflow: hidden;

[css box model does not stretch using padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089144/css-box-model-does-not-stretch-using-padding/12089237#12089237)