# Deleting overflow:hidden changes the layout

Tags: css, layout, overflow

The layout created by using the HTML and style below, became a mess after the overflow:hidden of the first container `<div>` was deleted (so that MathJax expressions did not get clipped). I am unable to find a simple solution to this and I will be grateful for any help.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="c0">
  <div class="d01">
   This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence.
  </div>
  <div class="d02">
   This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence. This is a repeated sentence.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="c1">
  <div class="d02">
   Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here.
  </div>
  <div class="d02">
    Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here.
  </div>
  <div class="d01">
   Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here. Some paragraph filler here.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Style**:

```
.c0 { background-color:#FF00FF; width:500px; margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; overflow:hidden; }

.d01 { background-color:#00FFFF; width:250px; float:right; margin-top: 3em; }

.d02 { background-color:#006666; width:150px; float:left; margin-top: 1em; }

.c1 { background-color:#666666; width:600px; margin: 0 auto; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Removing `overflow: hidden` causes the container looses its height, because of floated children: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not want to keep the `overflow:hidden;` propertie, wich triggers layout to be calculated including floatting element contained, you may use another value : `overflow:auto;` or use another technique.

`overflow:auto/*hidden*/;` , `display:inline-block/*inline-table/table/table-cell*/;` , `float:left/*right*/;` triggers layout.

Else you can add a last extra element or pseudo-element displayed **not** `inline` with `clear:both/*right/left*/;`, it is a communly called clearfix method.

some explanation here : http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. I will use a clear:both at the `.c1 div`. In the mean time I found out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128139/can-overflowhidden-affect-layout?rq=1) and the link to the [Magic of "overflow:hidden"]( http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) that may also help.

Answer (score 0):

use `clear:both;` and it will be fixed

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Please provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. For more read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).